# which threading concept is advisable to use in windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

i have a long running code (EG. getting details of remote machine). that takes 3 minutes to finish it work. i am using the following

1. Asynchronously, Need to get    each remote machine details .
2. Within short period time it needs to retrieve the details of all the remote machines  (Eg. 1000 machines in 3 minutes by threading concept).
3. for every 3 minutes it scan remote machines. for this, i used windows service.

for  the above criteria,

i used threading. in .net 4.0 many concepts are available tasks, task parellel library, thread and thread pool. among these 4 which one is best for windows service.

Note:

Some suggests in forums that using thread pool in windows service is not advisable. because onstop() in windows services wont work properly. because it waits until the thread pool finishes it work.

Answer (score 1):

> in .net 4.0 many concepts are available tasks, task parellel library, thread and thread pool

Task is a basic unit of Task Parallel Library (TPL).
TPL, in particular, uses the thread pool to schedule its tasks (but it isn't mandatory).
Thread pool uses threads to perform some work.

So, there are no so much concepts for threading, and the term "advisable" isn't applicable here.
Consider them as the abstraction levels on top of the "thread" concept.
I'd recommend you to start from the highest level available (TPL). From the task description, looks like [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if we using the TPL then how to stop the TPL tasks.

Comment: TPL uses graceful cancellation pattern. See this link for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx